# Docker Connection refused in localhost Window 10

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

In my Asp.Net core the localhost API run when I debugger
[image]

But when I publish in Docker. It's not working.

My container :

```
8ec8f59e7dde   04055a34c670   "dotnet ProductServi…"   8 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:9999->9999/tcp, :::9999->9999/tcp   interesting_mayer

"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "Http": {"Url": "http://localhost:9999"}
}
```

}

Docker information :
[image]
[image]

And here I use Window 10.

Thank you very much

Lamnv,

Answer (score 0):

It seems your docker is not configured correctly, you can fir more information regarding how to configure docker in this [PowerShell](https://github.com/iPazooki/MRPanel/blob/master/aspnet-core/build/build-with-ng.ps1) example.

Comment: sorry I dont understand that your post.Can you help me check it . my cource : https://github.com/LamNV0410/EshopSolution-Docker/blob/master/ProductServicec.API/Dockerfile. The docker into ProductService.Thank you very much

Comment: I fixed it. It wrong port . Thank you very much

Comment: @NguyenLam Sorry, I was busy these days. Glad you find the solution, so if my answer helped please mark it as an answer.